# Kinect and Unity, skeleton freedom

Tags: unity-game-engine, kinect

I'm using [this](http://wiki.etc.cmu.edu/unity3d/index.php/Microsoft_Kinect_-_Microsoft_SDK) package to work with kinect in Unity. But the skeleton keep freezed at a point, only members move normaly. I mean, i would expect that if I make a side step the skeleton would do too, but it stays at xyz 0,0,0.

Comment: Since we don't know how you have implemented the package you need to provide some code or tell us if you used the package right out of the box.  In the meantime I would log the position of the hip_center as you move.  If you don't see large changes in X/Z values then it's possible the data are normalized before getting to Unity.

Comment: I just imported the package and play. `hip_center` position is always `0, 7.8, 0`.

Comment: And just so I'm clear, you can see your limbs moving around relative to center, it's just that your entire skeleton doesn't move in the scene?

Answer (score 0):

that is not a problem is an option that you have set in the public boolean in the kinect sensor code. You need to uncheck it, sorry i forgot the name and i am at work but is very easy just pay attention to the scene you are working on.

Now i remember, its the offset option, you need to enable/disable that one in order to let move as you move.